# Camera Button like SnapChat

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin so I have no clue to implement this.
I want to implement a button like snapchat, where single click takes pic,
and on hold makes the button animation, and Button animation should be reset after the animation ends or after the user releases the finger
but in my code Either one of the Ontouch is only working.

my code for single tap

```
val gestureDetectorCompat = GestureDetectorCompat(applicationContext, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                Log.d("va","button lame")


                Log.d("va","button up")
                
              
                button.frame=0
                button.cancelAnimation()
                return super.onSingleTapUp(e)
            }

            
        })
        button.setOnTouchListener { _, event -> gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event) }
        button.isClickable=true
```

My code for Hold

```
button.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->


                    if (event.action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.d("actiondd","btn press?")
                       //here i want animation to start and end after 5 secs if user still holds the button
                        button.playAnimation()
                        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                        handler.postDelayed(
                            {
                                button.frame = 0
                               button.cancelAnimation()
                            }, 5000)

                   

                    } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {      
//Here i need animation to stop right after user removes finger             

                        button.frame = 0
                        button.cancelAnimation()
                        Log.i("heyyy", "anim stoppedd")
                    }
                    false
                }
```

Comment: You indicate that only one thing is working. What one thing is working?

Comment: @D.Kupra When i click the button once the whole animation starts playing and onsingletap does not work.

Comment: Yeah I agree that's weird. At least the TouchListener is responding correctly, so you got the harder part done. What was wrong with setting a simple onClick? Did setOnClickListener consume the event and not pass it to your TouchListener? Is that why you're not using it?

Comment: @D.Kupra No, but on click listens to Ontouch as well so when I want only Ontouch to work i.e at the end of Ontouch listener at ACTION_UP, Both Onclick and Ontouch gets triggered.

Comment: @D.Kupra Also I think the problem lies because I'm using two Ontouch listeners for the same button. I think so maybe...IDK

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question I have totally changed the code from my previous one.I have used Kotlin Timers and Ontouchlistener to achieve this[SnapChat camera button with animation].I have also implemented camera capture and video recording with cameraX with the same button.

```
//camera_capture_button is a lottie animation view
 camera_capture_button.setOnTouchListener{ v, event ->

            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("button","down")


                timer = object: CountDownTimer(5000, 500) {
                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        Log.d("timerr", fire.toString())
                        fire += 1

                        if(fire == 2){
                            if (isrecording==false) {
                                Log.d("timerr", "start recording")
                                takeVideo()
                                camera_capture_button.playAnimation()
                                vfx1.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                            }
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onFinish() {
                        Log.d("timerr","Timeup")
                        if (isrecording==true) {
                            stopRecording()
                            camera_capture_button.frame = 0
                            camera_capture_button.cancelAnimation()
                            vfx1.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    }
                }
                (timer as CountDownTimer).start()

                vfx1.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {

                    }

                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
//                        stopRecording()
//                        camera_capture_button.frame = 0
//                        camera_capture_button.cancelAnimation()
//                        vfx1.visibility=View.GONE
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                })
            }
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.d("timerr","up")
                timer?.cancel()
//                    stopRecording()
                if (fire<=2){
                    Log.d("timerr","tap")
                    takePic()
                }
                if (fire>2){
                    Log.d("timerr","stop recording")
                    stopRecording()
                }
                fire = 0
                camera_capture_button.frame = 0
                camera_capture_button.cancelAnimation()
                vfx1.visibility=View.GONE
            }

            true
        }
        camera_capture_button.isClickable=true
```